# Asp.Net Webforms: Using Identity roles upon registration

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, identity, roles

***Solved.. Figured it out on my own.**

Alright, I've searched and searched and even checked out the similar questions here. None of them are getting me what I need.

I currently have a Web Forms application that is using Identity. Right now I am trying to allow someone who is registering to choose from two different roles. One is Event Manager and the other is Data Entry.

I'm currently teaching myself .Net and using Web Forms. I see a lot of MVC references (I need to learn next) but since I don't know MVC yet it's hard to follow, especially since I'm just beginning. I already played with the Wingtip Toys tutorial that created an admin role into the programming, but how can I get this to work on the register page?

Is there anyone who can just point me in the right direction of where to start? Any good tutorials.

Comment: so, your problem is that you can register user but cannot add the user to a specific role?

Comment: I can register a user, but I'm looking to have a drop down or radio button option for someone who is registering to choose their roles.